# Connecting SATA to SATA

Tags: embedded, network-interface, sata

Is it possible to use the SATA interface to write data to it by PC and use the bus to transmit the data to another receiver SATA board ?

Comment: Well I guess if you have SATA receiver board it could be done because it's essentially how a SATA HDD works. But what's the real question on what you want to achieve? That would certainly be difficult to achieve for most people (myself included) and I can't think of an 'off-the-shelf' way to do it.

Comment: @PeterJ Just thought if SATA due to its high speed can be possible to network two CPUs or two Boards.

Comment: 2 10Gb Ethernet NICs will probably be easier, faster and (despite current prices) cheaper to implement.

Comment: @jippie my board doesn't have 10Gb ethernet

Comment: @Mahmoud neither does it have a receiver-SATA interface. So if you have to add hardware, then better add COTS (commercial off the shelf) hardware than custom made.

Comment: This reminds me that USB cannot be easily used to create a simple PC-PC home network connection either. The reason is the same.

Comment: @AlKepp Actually like 20 something years ago when we were all still using floppy disks I had a cable with two USB-A plugs on it and a little nub in the middle of the cable (presumably with a small circuit card in it).  It allowed me to transfer files directly between two computers via USB using a program that came with the cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the presence of an asymmetric host/device protocol on the SATA cable. The host puts itself in "sending a block to the disk" or "retrieving a block from the disk" state before transmitting content. There is no chance you could "force" the host on board R to be ready receiving just by sending content on board S, afaik.

If there's any chance for that to work, you'd need a custom device between the two cables that mimmics the operation of a disk, with a limited amount of RAM so that it can serve on cable B what it has received on cable A.